# Column '' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Error consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Me sale este error al querer hacer un select compuesto:

> Column 'Propietario.nombre_propietario' is invalid in the select list
> because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
> GROUP BY clause.

El codigo:

```
 create table Propietario(
 tipo_num_doc int primary key,
 nombre_propietario nvarchar(20),
 telefono_propietario int,
 cp int foreign key references Localidades(cp),
 )



create table Automoviles(
 cod_patente int primary key,
 marca_automovil nvarchar(60),
 modelo_auto nvarchar(60),
 color_auto nvarchar(60),
 tipo_auto nvarchar(10),
 tipo_num_doc int foreign key references Propietario(tipo_num_doc),
 )

--4 CUANTOS AUTOS TIENE CADA PROPRIETARIO

select Automoviles.tipo_num_doc, Propietario.nombre_propietario, count(cod_patente) from Automoviles 
inner join Propietario on Propietario.tipo_num_doc = Automoviles.tipo_num_doc
group by Automoviles.tipo_num_doc
```

Comment: este es uno de esos míticos casos en que el mensaje de error efectivamente es bastante claro. Te falta agregar la columna nombre_propietario en tu `GROUP BY`

Comment: Muchas gracias!